# JS, RegExp, weird behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

I use simple regexp pattern to validate email address, I found this pattern:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$
```

When I check the pattern on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) it behaves as expected(meaning it won't match for example `email@abcde`).

So the following line:

```
/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/.test('email@abcde'); // false
```

But:

```
let patt = new RegExp('^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$');
patt.test('email@abcde'); // true
```

**What?!**, I tested on chrome and firefox, same behavior, can anyone explain?

Comment: `\.` means something different in a regular expression literal than it does in a string literal.

Comment: `/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/.source !== '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\.` is not a valid escape sequence inside a **string literal**, it simply resolves to `.`. That means the regular expression you are using in the second example is equivalent to

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+.[^@]+$
```

And `.` matches any character.

You can easily see the difference if you log both regular expressions to the console:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't think about that, thanks, love the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `\.` is being evaluated as `.` in your regex. In other words, your regex is effectively: `^[^@]+@[^@]+.[^@]+$`

To fix, use the `//` regex delimiters:

```
patt = /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/
patt.test("email@abcde") // false
patt.test("email@abcde.com")  // true
```

Comment: or `patt = new RegExp('^[^@]+@[^@]+\\.[^@]+$')`